# How to make my method handle the response data coming from another source as a Redirect Url

Tags: grails, redirect

So i have an application that makes a request to another application, this other application accept a json object like

```
{
  "PBFPubKey": "FLWPUBK-4e581ebf8372cd691203b27227e2e3b8-X",
  "cardno": "5438898014560229",
  "cvv": "890",
  "expirymonth": "09",
  "expiryyear": "19",
  "currency": "NGN",
  "country": "NG",
  "amount": "10",
  "email": "user@gmail.com",
  .....,
  "meta": [{metaname: "flightID", metavalue: "123949494DC"}],
  "redirect_url": "https://server-ip/redirect-response",
  "device_fingerprint": "69e6b7f0b72037aa8428b70fbe03986c"
}
```

My problem is, how to i get the data object in the response when it come to the method "redirect-response" in the controller being called.

The response sent to the redirect url is

```
  {
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Some message",
    "data": {
      "someName": "Jon Thanos", 
      "date": "10-10-2019"
    }
  }
```

Kindly let me know if you do not understand something.

Just a quick one, the redirect get called alright, but i need to get the data coming

Answer (score 0):

So, i realised the redirect url from the other client was sending a post request.

So in my redirect url controller, thus the controller that receive the the request, i made the controller accept the request as a JSON

`JSONObject object = request.JSON as JSONObject`

The rest is to get the right objects from it.

Thanks all.